# Get Checkbox value if checked before ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to sumbit my forms and I added a checkbox to add an address to database if the checkbox is selected.  I am unsure of how to adjust my code to get the proper result.  as it stands now the jquery runs through each form input and gets the name and value to submit through ajax.  how can i adjust this code to not grab the checkbox if it is not checked.

my checkbox input field has an id of "addProperty" and a value of "yes"

here is my full jquery/ajax that submits my form.

```
 $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {


 $('body, html, div').scrollTop(0);

var refresh = $('#refUrl').val();




$.ajax({
    url: $("#form").attr("action"),
    type: $("#form").attr("method"),
    data: $("#form input").serialize(),
    success: function(response) {








            if (response === "success") {




                window.location.href = refresh;




            } else {


                $('.errors').append(response);



            }



        //flash messages
        var close = document.getElementsByClassName("closebtn");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
            close[i].onclick = function(){
                var div = this.parentElement;
                div.style.opacity = "0";
                setTimeout(function(){ div.style.display = "none"; }, 300);
            }
        }


        }



});

return false;
```

});

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: What does your html look like? You'll want to iterate through the container elements and if they contain a checked checkbox, then add the relevant data to your array.

Comment: Also, word of warning: Assigning `that` to be some variable, then reassigning it to be some other variable in another scope is a bad habit. Syntactically, it works, but it is confusing.

Comment: the checkbox input is not checked by default.

Comment: after reading the serialize stuff i can see that is what i want, but i don't know how to adjust my code to implement it.  i'm still trying to learn this stuff

Comment: All you need is `data: $(this).serialize()` for the ajax call, where `this` is the form Element.  The logic that you are trying to write for finding the inputs and build the map of them, is reinventing the wheel of what serialize() already does.

Comment: when i make that change the form now takes me to the form action url instead of performing the ajax call and leaving me on the page i was on with the result.  ugh..

Comment: everything i try gets my results, but it takes me to the form action page instead.  so i'm guessing its not doing the ajax.  i'm lost at this point.  i will update my question with the current code